# Shopify GraphQL not returning results for queries with special characters

Tags: reactjs, graphql, shopify

I have this query to get a product by tag category

Searching for `cd` category:

```
products(first:10, query:"tags:category:cd") {
    edges {}
}
```

I am getting results of this but if I search for `Yläosat`:

```
products(first:10, query:"tags:category:Yläosat") {
    edges {}
}
```

This query does not return results even though there are products in my Shopify having the tag `category:Yläosat`. I can also search by tag in Shopify products page using the string `category:Yläosat`. My guess is because of the special character in the word `Yläosat`. The problem is just in the graphql.

Comment: related graphql issue https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/256

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the tag in single quotes.

```
{
  products(first: 10, query:"tag:'category:Yläosat'"){
    edges {
      node {
        handle
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will fix the issue.

See the response below.

[image]